# How to use mockk to verify a member function was called?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I have a domain object. <1>

In a service class method, it calls domain instance's member function <2>

I want to verify this member function has been called.

How can I do this by `mockk`

```kotlin
data class Foo(val name: String) { <1>
    fun memberFunc() = "Data class: $name"
} 

@Service
class Service(val repo: Repo) {
    fun method(){
        val foo = repo.find()
        foo.memberFunc()           <2>
        otherMethod()
    }
    
    fun otherMethod() = "Call other method"
}

@Repository
class Repo() {
    fun find() = Foo("name")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mock the `Repo` and `Foo` classes.

```kotlin
val fooMock = mockk<Foo>()
every { fooMock.memberFunc() } return "A value"

val repoMock = mockk<Repo>()
every { repoMock.find() } return fooMock
```

Now you can use your test target class:

```kotlin
val testTarget = Service(repoMock)

testTarget.method()

verify {
  fooMock.memberFunc()
}
```

Consider this *pseudo-code*, but that's the general principle.

Comment: Thanks, this's what I want~ Also, I didn't learn spyk before I asked this question, now, I know I can use that to achieve the same goal as well.